# Change page backgrounds. LocalStorage

Tags: javascript

How to make sure that when you change the background color from the  in the same tab, the background color would be changed in the other? Now the background color changes when the page is reloaded. I want to do that when digging the two identical tabs, and update one of them would have changed the background and the other.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }

        .bg-1 {
            background: chocolate;
        }

        .bg-2 {
            background: aqua;
        }

        .bg-3 {
            background: grey;
        }

        h1 {
            color: white;
            font-size: 3em;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Change the background color of the page when you reload.</h1>

    <script>
        var body = document.body,
            currentStyle = +localStorage.currentStyle || 0;

        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            body.classList.add('bg-' + (currentStyle + 1));
            localStorage.currentStyle = ++currentStyle % 3;
        });

        window.addEventListener('storage', function( event ) {
            body.classList.remove('bg-' + event.oldValue);
            body.classList.add('bg-' + (currentStyle + 1));
            console.log(event.key);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you are looking for:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var body = document.body;

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var currentStyle = localStorage.getItem('currentStyle'),
            newStyle=1;
        if (currentStyle !== null) {
            newStyle = currentStyle % 3 + 1;
        } 

        body.classList.add('bg-' + newStyle);
        localStorage.setItem('currentStyle', newStyle);
    });

    window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
        var currentStyle = localStorage.getItem('currentStyle');
        body.classList.remove('bg-' + event.oldValue);
        body.classList.add('bg-' + currentStyle);
    });
</script>
```